# How can I use Liquid without Rails?

Tags: ruby, liquid

How can I use [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) without Rails? There is no information about this on [Liquid Wiki](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Using-liquid-without-rails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [Sinatra Recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/views/liquid), it's a yes you can.

Also you may want to check forks like [LiquidNode](https://github.com/sirlantis/liquid-node) if you need something that's non-ruby-based?